# PowerShell Multiple Where Filters to make Exclusion List

Tags: powershell

I am trying to build an exclusion list into my current filter for a Where-Object.

Currently I have the following:

```
Where-Object {($_.Enabled -EQ $true) -AND ($_.LastRunOutcome -eq 'failed')}
```

I want to add an additional filter that adds a dual filter.  So my main filter is on Enabled and LastRunOutcome, which will apply to all objects returned.

But I would also like to add a filter that says if the Name and SqlInstance match the string do not include in the output.

```
Where-Object {($_.Enabled -EQ $true -AND $_.LastRunOutcome -EQ 'failed' -AND $_.Name -NE "Import - Ad Hoc" -AND $_.SqlInstance -EQ "ServerName")}
```

Bonus points if you can help me figure out multiple Name/SqlInstance values. Example would be ServerA and NameA exclude, ServerB and NameB exclude, etc. This would allow for future exclusion values.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you're looking for in the simple case?

Input array for demonstration/testing:

```
$sqlInfo = @(
  @{ Enabled = $true; LastRunOutcome = 'failed'; Name = 'name0'; SqlInstance = 'instance0' }
  @{ Enabled = $false; LastRunOutcome = 'failed'; Name = 'name0'; SqlInstance = 'instance0' }
  @{ Enabled = $true; LastRunOutcome = 'succeeded'; Name = 'name0'; SqlInstance = 'instance0' }
  @{ Enabled = $false; LastRunOutcome = 'succeeded'; Name = 'name0'; SqlInstance = 'instance0' }
  @{ Enabled = $true; LastRunOutcome = 'failed'; Name = 'name0'; SqlInstance = 'instance1' }
  @{ Enabled = $true; LastRunOutcome = 'failed'; Name = 'name1'; SqlInstance = 'instance0' }
  @{ Enabled = $true; LastRunOutcome = 'failed'; Name = 'name1'; SqlInstance = 'instance1' }
)
```

Filter script:

```
$result = $sqlInfo | Where-Object { ($_.Enabled -eq $true -and $_.LastRunOutcome -eq 'failed') `
  -and -not ($_.Name -eq 'name0' -and $_.SqlInstance -eq 'instance0')}
```

Output script and result:

```
$result | ForEach-Object { [PSCustomObject]$_ } | Format-Table

Name  LastRunOutcome SqlInstance Enabled
----  -------------- ----------- -------
name0 failed         instance1      True
name1 failed         instance0      True
name1 failed         instance1      True
```

**BONUS**
If you can perform a sort of concatenation of the server name and instance, it should be fairly straight forward to filter on an exclusion list by using `contains` on an array of strings.

```
$exclusionSet = @(
  'name0 -- instance0'
  'name1 -- instance1'
)

$result = $sqlInfo | Where-Object { ($_.Enabled -eq $true -and $_.LastRunOutcome -eq 'failed') `
  -and -not ($exclusionSet.Contains("$($_.Name) -- $($_.SqlInstance)" ) ) }

$result | ForEach-Object { [PSCustomObject]$_ } | Format-Table
```